# Expandable ListView Auto Set Parent and Child

Tags: android, arrays, expandablelistview

I am looking to create an `ExpandableListView` in android from 1 database. I am pulling a row from the database and setting the database to a object array which has 3 items.

---

|Name|Rank|Description|

---

Is there a way to set the parents to unique values in the Rank and then place the name and description of those ranks as the children?